# SPELL CHECKER IN C++

Tags: dictionary, spell-checking

Hello I am new here so i may not be able to ask my question properly, actually i am given an assignment in which we are to make a spell checker using trie data structure. I’ve learned how to insert and search in trie data structure but now i am confused, do i have to once load all the dictionary words as strings into my programme then ask user to input the word he want to input or is there any other way as this will be really time consuming?

Comment: What do you mean by "time consuming"?  If it's program time - with a proper trie implementation, reading in a full English word list (even if it's c. 100k words and 1M total characters - my measurements from `/usr/share/dict/words` on my Linux system) should still take only a fraction of a second on any modern system.

Comment: like how can i insert 1M words into my program?

Comment: how can i make my program read a full english word list? should i need to use file handling concept to do so?

Comment: Yes, usually reading the words from a file would be the way to go.  (That said, I don't know the details of your assignment, which might be specifying something else to avoid getting ahead of the logical progression - for all I know, the assignment might be asking you to input a very limited dictionary by hand.)